# In karate-Gatling framework-- can we have multiple scenarios with multiple assertion in one simulation file?

Tags: karate

How can I have different assertion for all the scenarios in one simulation file.
I want to keep different maximum latency for each scenario in one simulation file.

Code Example

```
setUp(
Scenario1.inject(constantUsersPerSec(10)during(20 seconds)).assertions(
forAll.responseTime.max.it(maxLatency1)).protocols(protocol),
Scenario2.inject(constantUsersPerSec(10)during(20 seconds)).assertions(
forAll.responseTime.max.it(maxLatency2)).protocols(protocol)
)
```

Error Message: simulation compilation failed.

Also, I tried to keep multiple setup section for each scenario in one simulation file, but in that case I get error message-- set up can only be set once.

Please let me know if there is any way to set different latency for every scenario in single simulation file.